# Why is my laptop not charging? The led indicater does not light up but the laptop thinks it plugged in

Tags: laptop, battery, power, laptop-repair, hp-elitebook

I have a Elitebook 820 G3 laptop.
As far as I could tell the battery held charge well until it suddenly stopped charging. When plugged in the led charging indicator does not light up. However the laptop reconizes its plugged in at the icon tray
The battery does not charge. What do i do to fix this?

[image: icon tray says laptop is plugged in]

I ran this battery diagnostic does it mean that the battery is bad are can it still fail because of a short?

[image]

Comment: Two possibilities:  Laptop hardware error.   Dead (dying) battery. Take it to a local repair shop.

Comment: I opened up the laptop, the battery was puffy. I replaced the battery and everything now works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LED light not indicating that it is plugged in leads me to believe that this is a hardware issue, such as a short. Sadly, hardware issues are often harder than software issues to detect and resolve over the internet.

My suggestions for testing and fixing this problem are, in this order, thus:

- Buy a new charger and test it
- Buy a new battery and test it
- Send the laptop in to a repair shop, while explicitly stating that you have tested both the battery and the charger

Reasoning: Charging units and batteries are inexpensive and the charger, at least, should be easy to retrieve a refund for. Meanwhile, not everybody has access to a soldering iron for replacing and reconnecting wires on the inside of a computer.

Comment: My money would be on the battery. That model was introduced 6 years ago, and a couple years in, your Li Ion battery will already start losing charge. If you can borrow a charger from someone (any HP one with the same plug, voltage and sufficient wattage will do) you could rule that one out (this is the least likely cause of the problem though I reckon). The third option, "something else" is somewhere in between, but also the most expensive.

Comment: @wanwandrew I did a battery test and it failed does that mean the problem is the battery?

Comment: @MiG would you suggest openning up the laptop first to see if there are any shorts? as that sounds like the cheapest option

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that option unless I know the person knows what an antistatic wristband is and *really* knows how not to wreck things :x

Comment: This is why I suggested borrowing a charger btw, batteries tend to be model specific (usually because of the shape) so borrowing will likely be difficult, but chargers are usually exchangeable for most models of a single brand (do *always* check if the voltage matches and the minimum wattage is sufficient for your model though). Maybe you're lucky and it's the charger, that's your cheapest fix. Battery's more expensive but more likely to be the culprit. Option 3, "anything else" would probably be the most expensive.

Comment: @joe If the new battery is able to be charged, then the old battery was the issue.